# Voltage drop in synchronous rectifier for post regulation of low voltage rail in multi-output PS?

Tags: power-supply, rectifier

Consider a supply for 3.3 V (V1) and 24 V (V2), 96 W each.

I'd expect synchronous rectification with V1, and post regulation with V2.

To decrease the Volt-seconds for an inductor, it seems conventional to "reduce the on-time".
Is it possible to have V2 the one with feedback, and post-regulate V1 via increasing the voltage drop in the MOSFETs used as diodes?
Would it be useful when the voltages are as disparate as 24&3.3? I can see why just shortening on-time looks good with voltages close, the shortened-on-time close to the primary one.

Comment: Has it been done commercially?

Comment: Yes, if the 96-W output is obtained by rectifying a pulsing waveform, like the output of a forward or buck converter, then you can with leading-edge modulation implement a post-regulated synchronous rectifier. There was the [NCP4331](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp4331-d.pdf) long ago and there are probably newer ICs out there. I did document a solution in my [book](https://www.amazon.com/Switch-Mode-Power-Supplies-Second-Edition/dp/0071823468/ref=dp_ob_image_bk) on SMPS (p873) after discussing mag-amps post regulators.

Comment: (I remember magnetic post regulators. I feel old.) (2nd. ed. looks promising.)

Comment: `NCP4331` or analog's LT3710. Same as magnetic post regulation, I didn't want to mention it in the question.

Comment: (Down-voters please comment.)